# Agroa screen sharing in android CRASH

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, foreground-service, agora.io, screensharing

Sample Code :- When i implemented following code that i got from Agora offical website Link https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_android?platform=Android

I run this code on Android 9.

```
MediaProjectionManager projectManager = (MediaProjectionManager) mContext.getSystemService(
Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

// Create the intent for screen capture. Call the startActivityForResult method to use the sharing function.
Intent intent = projectManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent);

MediaProjection projection;
VirtualDisplay display;

// Override and implement the onActivityResult method of the Activity where you just called startActivityForResult.
@Override
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resuleData) {
    projection = projectManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);
    display = projection.createVirtualDisplay(name, width, height, dpi, flags, surface, callback, handler);
}

// The texture retrieved from the Surface will be sent by the SDK.
rtcEngine.pushExternalVideoFrame(new AgoraVideoFrame(...));

// Stop screen sharing.
projection.stop();
```

When i run this code i got following crash on this line :-  `projection = projectManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);`

Crash :-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=8899, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.fantka_live/com.fantka_live.ui.activity.agora_live_stream_module.LiveActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4846)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4887)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take this Share Screen demo code for reference: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/Android/sample-switch-external-video

Comment: I already gone through with this repository, thanks by the way you have any another solution?

Comment: How about this one: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/dev/win-screenshare/Screensharing/Agora-Screen-Sharing-Android